# stripe subscription fail other than first one with test account

Tags: stripe-payments

When subscription is done, first day payment succeed, but fails following days.

[image: failure image]

I used test card data 4242 4242 4242 4242, so it must succeed.

code

```
const options = 
{
   "customer":"cus_K7bjvfmQNzcEXl",
   "items":[
      {
         "price":"price_1JSPPwLJhlpUSQhv1nJznb1r"
      }
   ],
   "discounts":[
      
   ],
   "add_invoice_items":[
      {
         "price":"price_1JTKysLJhlpUSQhvI0YAj3B0"
      }
   ],
   "payment_behavior":"default_incomplete",
   "expand":[
      "latest_invoice.payment_intent"
   ]
}

this.stripe.subscriptions.create(options);
```

items price is set as recurring everyday subscription.
what is the reason of failure?

[update after I got comment]
the error is like this.

[image]

Comment: If you click into the failures in the Stripe console it should tell you the reason.

Comment: @ceejayoz

thanks, I added error screen

Comment: Scroll down further, to the "payments" section. https://imgur.com/a/1EiqFu6

Answer (score 0):

After/When you attach a payment method to the customer, you would still need to set `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` [0] so that this payment method will be used as the customer’s default payment method for subscriptions and invoices.

You can read about this in more detail here : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements#default-payment-method

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method